# VB .NET Access UserControl1's controls from form

Tags: .net

I have an usercontrol and a form1.
But, i'm unable to access the Usercontrol's controls, like the buttons or listbox that are on the Usercontrol from my Form1.

How can i access them?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you drop a Textbox onto the form in the designer and go to the code and try to do `textbox1.Text = "some value"` what happens? Do the controls show up in the designer.vb file?

Comment: Hello, of course sorry.

Here is for example my form1 :

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   MyBase.Load  
        UserControl1.Label1.text = "test"  
    End Sub  

I want to access the Usercontrol1.label1 from my form1